# VS2017 docker-compose vs docker-compose.override?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

Environment:

Windows 10 Enterprise
Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Docker CE 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513)

When I create a solution and add Docker support, VS2017 creates a docker-compose project and adds docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml. Is there a difference between the two files? Reason I ask is I was trying to set an environment variable on a per container basis.

If I do this in the docker-compose.**override**.yml file as:

```
services:
  webapplication1:
    environment:
      - TEST=HELLO1
    ports:
      - "80"
```

It builds and works as expected.

If I do it in docker-compose.yml as:

```
services:
  webapplication1:
    image: compositeapp
    environment:
      - TEST=HELLO1
    build:
      context: .\WebApplication1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Now it no longer builds and gives me an error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       (Line: 6, Col: 7, Idx: 73) - (Line: 6, Col: 7, Idx: 73): Expected 'MappingStart', got 'SequenceStart' (at Line: 6, Col: 7, Idx: 73).    docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets  294

Why do some things need to go in the main file and some in the override? From documentation I've seen, there's generally only the main compose file. Is the override a VS2017 specific thing?

Answer (score 0):

That was an bug in a specific build of the Docker tooling in VS, it is fixed in 15.8 preview 3 or later. You can choose to upgrade or use the workaround mentioned here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/98